# Doing db.find with non primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

So what im trying to do is im trying to get an user from my database where the email im trying to find matches an email in my database. If i had the id instead of the email i could just do an db.user.find(id) but i only have the email so im trying to use where but without success.

this is my code

```
// POST: api/User_Agendapunt1
        [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostUser_Agendapunt(User user1)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            User user = db.User.Where(o => o.Email== user1.Email);

            var user_dagpunten = from s in db.User_agendapunt
                                 where s.UserId == user.IdUser
                                 select s;


            return Ok(user_dagpunten.ToList());
        }
```

EDIT1:
[image]

Comment: `User user = db.User.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Email == user1.Email)`

Comment: Just tried but i have no idea if it worked. I have added breakpoints to all line possible and after it runs User user = db.User.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Email == user1.Email)  line it skips all the rest after and goes out of my method without even running the return Ok line. I have no idea if this is related to my previous issue.

Comment: Could it be that user1 is null? and you get `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Just for testing purpose wrap `User user = db.User.Where(o => o.Email== user1.Email);` in try/catch and put a breakpoint inside catch block

Comment: No there is a string of email. And i dont get any exeption at all it just exits the method as a whole.

Comment: No alex doesnt happen anything it doenst even enter the catch it just leaves the method

Comment: Why are you returning the user list? you need to find single user or there willl be multiple matches?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue dont really know how but i got past the point of my question. haim770 his answer was correct about finding the the right user that matches the email dont think my other issues had to do anything with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
User user= db.User.Where(x=> x.Email==user1.Email).FirstOrDefault();


 if(user !=null)
  {
   // do your stuff
  }
  else{
   //return no user exist with given email
  }
```

Hope this solves your issue ...

Comment: That's not a find.  That's a table scan over the entire collection.  If this ever turns into a real product, the table scans will kill your performance.